# How to work with NSOperation Queue in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am getting error with following code, I am using NSOperationQueue to get post data from server. At the time of login i want to get response from server totally 8 times. For this i am using NSOperationQueue, but it's not working properly. Some times i am getting this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

self.operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                        selector:@selector(getDataFromServer2)
                                                                          object:nil];

[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

// The same story as above, just tell here to execute the colorRotatorTask method.
operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(getDataFromServer3)
                                                   object:nil];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(getDataFromServer4)
                                                   object:nil];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(getDataFromServer5)
                                                   object:nil];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(getDataFromServer6)
                                                   object:nil];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(getDataFromServer7)
                                                   object:nil];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(getDataFromServer8)
                                                   object:nil];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

MY JSON Code is

```
- (void) getDataFromServer2 {

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***********?”];

NSLog(@"%@", str);

self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
self.url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
self.urlReq = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:self.url];
[self.urlReq setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[self.urlReq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@“*=&&”];

NSLog(@“Post : %@", post);

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long) [postData length]];
[self.urlReq setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[self.urlReq setHTTPBody:postData];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    self.dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:self.urlReq completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (!(data == nil)) {

            NSError *error;
            self.loginDic2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@", error);

            self.integer2 = [[self.loginDic2 objectForKey:@"id"] count];
            NSLog(@"self.integer2 : %lu", self.integer2);
            NSLog(@"Login Dic2 : %@", self.loginDic2);

            if ([[self.loginDic2 objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"SUCCESS"]) {

                    self.ID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    self.m = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    for (int i=0; i<self.integer2; i++) {

                        [self.ID addObject:[[[self.loginDic2 objectForKey:@“d”] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"]];
                        [self.m addObject:[[[self.loginDic2 objectForKey:@“d”] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"m"]];

                    }

                    NSLog(@"cast_nm : %@", self.m);


                    [self.defaults setObject:self.cast_nm forKey:@"m"];
                    [self.defaults synchronize];

                });

            } else {

                NSString *str = [self.loginDic2 objectForKey:@"error_code"];

                if ([str isEqualToString:@"104"]) {
                    self.noRecordsFound = @"No Records Found.";
                } else {
                    self.noRecordsFound = @"Invalid Parameters.";
                }

                UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle : @"Message"
                                                                                message : self.noRecordsFound
                                                                         preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction
                                      actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                      { }];

                [alert addAction:ok];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                });

            }

        } else {

            UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle : @"Message"
                                                                            message : @"No server response."
                                                                     preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction
                                  actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                  { }];

            [alert addAction:ok];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            });

        }

    }];  [self.dataTask resume];
});
}
```

I ma using the same code 8 times ....

Comment: I think you dont need to use NSOperationQueue if you use NSURLSession because it is an operationQueue. Setting delegateQueue to nil makes it default type (ie serial queue).

Comment: But am getting error while store values in Array. So that a why I am using queue

Comment: It might be cause by other cause. My guess is it is not caused by not using NSOperationQueue. If you execute this code 8 times, then 8 of them will run serially, only the order is unknown. So you need to take care of that manually.

Comment: This has nothing to do with NSOperationQueue, put a break point at self.loginDic2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; and check if loginDic2 is actually a array of JSON objects or not! I believe its nil hence crashing may be server is not sending data or the data sent is not a JSON array thats all

Comment: Above Gencode comment is correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `self.ID addObject` or `self.m addObject`. It appears that sometimes the object you are trying to insert is `nil` and you can't insert a `nil` into an array.

Other issue I can see with your code is that you are using strong reference to `self` inside a block which may cause memory leaks.